# Relative Python Modules

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a lot of trouble understanding the python module import system.

I am trying to create a simple folder structure as follows.

```
SomeModule
   __init__.py
   AnotherModule
       AnotherModule.py
       __init__.py
       Utils
           Utils.py
           __init__.py
```

To use SomeModule i can do:

```
SomeModule.Foo()
```

Now inside AnotherModule.py I would like to import my Utils directory.

How come I have to do

```
import SomeModule.AnotherModule.Utils.Foo
```

why cannot I just do

```
import Utils.Foo
```

Comment: Because _explicit is better than implicit._

Comment: So a module must always know its full path? You can never move a module into another module directory without changing every import in the file?

Comment: You could have a go at `import .Utils` if you're feeling brave ..

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding this question. When you say `import Utils.Foo`, you are implying that `Foo` is a *module* within the `Utils` *package*, otherwise the statement doesn't make sense. So you would have to have a `Foo.py` file within the `Utils` directory.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean by "use" `SomeModule`. Where exactly is the statement `SomeModule.Foo()`? If that statement works, you're saying that there is a function (or callable class) named `Foo` within the `SomeModule` module or package. So it's in the `SomeModule/__init__.py` file? Why are you comparing the import behavior of a Foo function (in SomeModule) with a Foo module (in Utils)?

Comment: Regardless, you should read [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/). One thing you'll see there is that there is no such thing as a relative import without the `from` keyword. If the statement starts with `import` and has no `from`, then it is an absolute import, without exception. Also check out [this other Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time). There's a lot of information on that page, as well as many links right at the top which are likely to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

To shorten up the actual function name that you'll have to call in your code, you can always do:

```
from SomeModule.AnotherModule.Utils import *
```

While this still won't allow you to get away with a shorter import statement at the top of your script, you'll be able to access all of the functions within `.Utils` just by calling their function name (i.e. `foo(x)` instead of `SomeModule.AnotherModule.Utils.foo(x)`.

Part of the reason for the lengthy import statement goes to the comment from @wim . Have a look by typing `import this` in a python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

put

```
import sys
import SomeModule.AnotherModule
sys.modules['AnotherModule'] = SomeModule.AnotherModule
```

in SomeModules `__init__.py`